# Override service in hybris smart edit 2015

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, smartedit

How to override service.

```
@SeDowngradeService()
export class EditorEnablerService {} // This service is called when edit button is clicked
```

It calls this.openEditorModalService.open()

```
@SeDowngradeService(IEditorModalService)
@GatewayProxied('open', 'openAndRerenderSlot', 'openGenericEditor')
export class EditorModalService extends IEditorModalService {}
```

But

```
this.openEditorModalService.open()
```

opens the out of the box generic editor it is not calling our customized generic editor modal.

Comment: Title says `2015`, isn't it `2105`?